# NBodySimulation

Tags: differential-equations

My question is about new NBodySimulation package in version 12.
I figured out how to customize the basic functions "PairwisePotential", "PairwiseForce","ExternalPotetial"...
The next unresolved issue for me, is whether any of those functions could be made time dependent (?)
A particular application I have in mind, is N-body system in e.g. heat-bath, represented as external potential or force.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I thought of adding time as another dynamic variable, and setting "ExternalPotential" (or Force) as function of space-time. But I haven't tried it yet.